# Button Vs Links in a SPA such as React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, single-page-application

Which one should I use inside a SPA application?? Considering the user Experience.

I have designed my applications using React with some personal rules, but which one would be the right way to use?

Buttons:

- For small actions (close a tooltip, a notification badge...)
- With forms
- When you don't need to worry with event flows

Links

- To change a route / page
- Anchor links
- Link inside texts

Like I said, getting confuse here to distinguish the use and purpose of each one.

Answer (score 11):

Generally, my distinguishing factor is that Buttons execute an action whereas Links navigate you to a different portion of a website, generally undoable with the back button.

Some common Buttons:

- Save Button (on a form)
- Post Your Answer (stack overflow question answer)
- Log In
- Send Email

Some Common Links:

- Home, Profile (facebook)
- Questions (stack overflow)
- Notifications (twitter)
- Popular (reddit)

As a metric for which to use, I usually like to ask if the thing I'm doing would be able to be undone with the back button on the browser. You can't "back button" a login request, or a tweet, but you can "back button" navigation to your profile on facebook or a link on reddit.

Comment: That's a awesome way Alex! Your question is great: the thing I'm doing would be able to be undone with the back button on the browse! Thanks YOU!